# A test do check the circularity of a complex variable

Tags: density-function, complex-numbers

I need a way to measure the circularity of a complex random variable. A complex random variable is circular when its PDF depends only on its magnitude and does not depends on its angle.

For example, $z$ been a complex random variable $z=x+iy$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and $x$ and $y$ are real random variables the PDF of $z$ ($f(z)$) can be writen only in function of $|z|$ if $z$ is circular.

Some papers uses the pseudo-variance normalized by the variance ($\phi_z$) of the variable to tell if the variable is circular:

$$\phi_z=\frac{E[z^2]}{E[zz^*]}$$

Because $\phi_z=0$ if $z$ is circular, but a complex variable can have $\phi_z=0$ and not been circular if its real and imaginary part are orthogonal. As exemplified on the scatter chart of the real and imaginary part of samples of a non-circular variable below where $\phi_z=0$:

[image]

It's obvious that the probability dense changes not only with the magnitude of the sample.

Since the PDF does not depends on the angle, in a circular variable, the samples must be evenly distribuited on all interval of angle (ie $-\pi$ to $\pi$). The following image shows an example of a circular random variable and the PDF of the angles of it's samples estimated with a histogram:

[image]
[image]

So, I came up with the ideia of perform a hypotesis test to check the circularity of the variable, where:

$H_0$: Variable angle's PDF is uniform

$H_1$: Variable angle's PDF is not uniform

So $H_0$ correspond to the variable been circular

Is this test valid? Is there a paper that proposes that test? Is there a better way to check the circularity of a complex random variable?

Comment: You haven't proposed any test: you have merely expressed how any formal hypothesis test of circularity must work in the most general setting (that is, without specifying a narrower alternative hypothesis).  Moreover, hypothesis tests are not measurements, but you ask at the outset how to *measure* circularity.  So, although you set out an interesting circumstance, it's unclear what you are trying to ask about it.  Could you edit your post to show us what you need?